# near "',user'":syntax error Unable to execute statement

Tags: qt, syntax

I am having a mare of a time with a test program I am trying to create in QT.

I am using SQLTE database for employee info and trying to get my user management section to update and save new users on click button.

I am using the following code on push button click but I get the following error; near "',user'":syntax error Unable to execute statement and for the life of me I cannot work out why..

Can someone help.

```
void oviewsettings::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
QString Name, Surname, Access, Phone, Email, Username, Password;
Name=ui->lineEdit_usermanagement_Name->text();
Surname=ui->lineEdit_usermanagement_Surname->text();
Access=ui->lineEdit_usermanagement_Access->text();
Phone=ui->lineEdit_usermanagement_Phone->text();
Email=ui->lineEdit_usermanagement_Email->text();
Username=ui->lineEdit_usermanagement_Username->text();
Password=ui->lineEdit_usermanagement_Password->text();



OViewMain conn;
if(!conn.connOpen()){
    qDebug()<<"Failed to open the database";
    return;
}
conn.connOpen();
QSqlQuery qry;
qry.prepare("insert into employeeinfo ([Name],[Surname],[Access],[Phone],[Email],[Username],[Password]) values ('"+Name+"',"+Surname+"',"+Access+"','"+Phone+"','"+Email+"','"+Username+"','"+Password+"')");

if(qry.exec("insert into employeeinfo ([Name],[Surname],[Access],[Phone],[Email],[Username],[Password]) values ('"+Name+"',"+Surname+"',"+Access+"','"+Phone+"','"+Email+"','"+Username+"','"+Password+"')"))
{
    QMessageBox::critical(this,tr("Save"),tr("Database Updated, Saved"));
    conn.connClose();
}
else
{
    QMessageBox::critical(this,tr("Error"),qry.lastError().text());
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing apostrophe before `"+Surname+"'` and `"+Access+"'`. Plus there are more strange things in your code, but they probably do not cause the error. For example why do you call `connOpen()` twice or why do you repeat the query code in `prepare()` and in `exec()`? And if you are serious about error handling, you should also check return value from `prepare()`.

Comment: Thanks for spotting the ' at +Surname+ and +Access+ I am new to this. I originally did not havce the query code in prepare() and exec() but it threw an error when I removed it from exec() so I placed it there which seemed to resolved the error.

Further information around checking the return value from prepare() would be excellent

One connOpen is with a ! if it is not open return;

Comment: Now I have repaired the ' at +surname+ and +access+ it throws a No query Unable to fetch row error. Are you able to help?

Comment: I suggest that you create a new question to Stack Overflow because this is a new type of error. Your original error was solved. In the new question you should also show your new code because without seeing it, we cannot help you.